# Drawing a hexagon node which further needs to be used in a flowchart

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

I need to draw a hexagon node [image: something like shown in the picture]
please help.

Comment: it would be helpful if you include a handrawn sketch of the flowchart where you intend to use the hexagon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it should be stretched as shown in your sketch, you can use

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,shape border rotate=30,draw,
    minimum size=1cm,yscale=3]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to stretch it, drop `,yscale=3`.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is unclear. So far I didn't see such (oriented) a shape in flowchart diagrams. Probably it should be rotated for 90 degrees:

[image]

which can be simply drawn by use of the `shapes.symbols` TikZ library:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
\node[signal, signal to=east and west, draw] at (0,1) {To East and West};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you Zarko and abcdefg for helping me with the drawing.

Comment: The accepted answer works, and is a hexagon. Your answer has the wrong aspect angles. Just refrain from blackmailing other posts just because you do not understand them.

Comment: You can use it like any other node.

Comment: Sorry, I do not buy this. You refer to the "accepted" solution and question if it is useful. This has only one purpose. Just remove the above comment and do not try to discredit codes by others. If you do not understand them this does not imply that they are not worthwhile.

Comment: @abcdefg, I will not argue with you. This is just wast of time.